# Nuget C++ packages has flooded my solution with files

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I have used Nuget C++ to download boost packages for my project. While it seems to function fine Nuget has put most of the source files it downloaded into my "Source Files" filter, and I can't remove them from there.

Is this a problem with the package? or does Nuget do this all the time?
pic:

[image: flooded with boost]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Boost source libraries such as [boost_regex](http://www.nuget.org/packages/boost_regex/). Source libraries are required only for unknown compilers/platforms. Use pre-compiled Boost Nuget packages instead, for example [boost_regex-vc120](http://www.nuget.org/packages/boost_regex-vc120). See [a list of all Boost NuGet packages](http://getboost.codeplex.com/releases/view/614528).